# How to read data from data/data/my_package

Tags: android

I have downloaded a video file into `data/data/my_package/video.mp4` and now i want to know how i can play this video. I am using Eclipse. Thanks in advance.

```
 DownloadFromUrl("PATH"+videoname.mp4)
{

public void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName) {

            try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.bestbusinessplaces.com/animation/admin/Animation/132404046113240392391323340839intelligent_cartridge.mp4-muxed_0.mp4-muxed.mp4"); //you can write here any link

                   File file = new File(fileName);

                   long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    tv.setText("Starting download......from " + url);

                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();

                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                    /*

                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).

                     */

                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                    int current = 0;

                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {

                            baf.append((byte) current);

                    }


                   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                   fos.write(baf.toByteArray());

                   fileOutput.close();
                   fos.close();

                    tv.setText("Download Completed in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

            } catch (IOException e) {

                 tv.setText("Error: " + e);

            }

    }
```

Comment: What is the permission for this video file?

Comment: -rw------- this is permission of this video file

Comment: this is not working OutputStream myOutput = openFileOutput("Video_filename.mp4", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: may be i m doing wrong so please give me a sample code if possible please

Comment: i have added the code please check it and tell me how i can play video from data/data/my_package

Comment: in PATH=/data/data/my_package_name

Comment: I edited my answer, try this code it works fine..

Comment: what is the absolute path of "test_video.mp4"

Comment: where this( "test_video.mp4") file is storing????

Comment: Thanks for your time..file permission has been changed... thank u so much but my main problem is that i want to play this video

Comment: Try this on device, you will get video played, video stored at /data/data/package_name/test_video.mp4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store video's in internal storage make sure its have `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` permission so media player can access it,

So, Store video something like,

```
OutputStream myOutput = openFileOutput("Video_filename.mp4", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

and then use the path to set video source..

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.mypackage/myfile");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
```

**EDIT:**

```
 URL url;        
 URLConnection ucon = null;

 url = new URL("http://www.bestbusinessplaces.com/animation/admin/Animation/132404046113240392391323340839intelligent_cartridge.mp4-muxed_0.mp4-muxed.mp4");
 ucon = url.openConnection();
 InputStream is = null;
 is = ucon.getInputStream();
 OutputStream myOutput = openFileOutput("test_video.mp4", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

 try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ( (length = is.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
           myOutput.write(buffer);
      }

   //Close the streams
   myOutput.flush();
   myOutput.close();
   is.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {

      }
```